# Adding items to list without list instance

Tags: c#, list

```
   PraseItems(Ilist<int> items)
    {
    ....
    }
```

Why does the following syntax throw error but other is not

```
   ParseItems(new List<int>().Add(5)); -- throws Invalid arguments error

   ParseItems(new List<int>(5)); -- No error
```

Comment: Why did you tag C in this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right syntax is

```
  new List<int>() { 5 };
```

In your sample

```
  List<int>(5)
```

you're just allocating memory for 5 items